# No attached payment source for Stripe subscription creation

Tags: java, stripe-payments

I'm currently migrating my app from using the Stripe Charges API to use the Stripe PaymentIntents API, in order to comply with SCA regulations.

My subscription creation code roughly looks like this:

```
Map<String, Object> srchOpts = new HashMap<>();
srchOpts.put("email", userEmail);   

List<Customer> matchingCustomers = Customer.list(srchOpts).getData();
Customer customer = null;
Subscription subscription = null;

if ( matchingCustomers.isEmpty() ){
    Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    params.put("email", userEmail);
    params.put("payment_token", stripeToken);
    customer = Customer.create(params);
}
else if (matchingCustomers.size() == 1) {
    customer = matchingCustomers.get(0);
    Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    params.put("source", stripeToken);
    PaymentSourceCollection paymentSources = customer.getSources();
    paymentSources.create(params);
}

Map<String, Object> item = new HashMap<String, Object>();
item.put("plan", planId); // e.g. my-pro-plan (no trial days)

Map<String, Object> items = new HashMap<String, Object>();
items.put("0", item);

Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>();
params.put("items", items);

params.put("customer", customer.getId());
params.put("off_session", false);
subscription = Subscription.create(params);
```

I can see on the Stripe dashboard (in test mode) that the customer is created and has the card which I specified, but the Subscription.create call fails with:

> com.stripe.exception.InvalidRequestException: This customer has no attached payment source; code: resource_missing

The customer has a card set (there is only 1 so it has to be the default card), the customer creation call happens before the subscription creation call and the customer ID is being passed to the sub creation call. Is there some other parameter I need to pass in?

---

I've tried setting `Customer.invoice_settings.default_payment_method` when the customer is being created, and that gets me past the subscription creation. Everything looks fine from the Stripe dashboard, except that I'm testing with an SCA test card, so the transaction is incomplete until the customer has authenticated further.

I need the client secret token from the response to continue, and I thought that I would get it from `#Subscription.getLatestInvoiceObject().getPaymentIntentObject().getClientSecret()` but the `getLatestInvoiceObject()` call is returning `null`.

I'm not setting `collection_method` on the Subscription object which defaults to `charge_automatically`. This is what I want because the customer is on-session and so the `Invoice` being `null` probably makes sense, but how do I get the client secret to pass back to the frontend? The `SetupIntent` object returned by the subscription response exposes a client secret, but that object is `null` too.

Answer (score 4):

Subscription `Invoices` will use whichever of these three payment options are available (in order of preference):

1. The `Subscription`'s `default_payment_method` ([reference](https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/create#create_subscription-default_payment_method)) or `default_source` ([reference](https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/create#create_subscription-default_source))
2. The `Customer`'s `invoice_settings.default_payment_method` ([reference](https://stripe.com/docs/api/customers/object#customer_object-invoice_settings-default_payment_method))
3. The `Customer`'s `default_source` (note: there is no concept of a default PaymentMethod on Customers)

Also worth noting is that PaymentMethods and Sources are two distinct resources. Cards (objects with ids prefixed with `card_`) can be used as either type.

Comment: So, does that mean that I have to explicitly set the `invoice_settings.default_payment_method` OR the `default_source`on the newly created Customer immediately after creating it with a Customer Update call? And if so, is there no way to specify the default during the customer creation call?

Comment: You can [create a Customer with a Source](https://stripe.com/docs/sources/customers#attaching-a-source-to-a-new-customer-object) (either `src_` or `card_` objects).

Comment: Before I began my API updates, my customer creation code used to set the `source` parameter with the token I received from Stripe.js at the frontend e.g. `Stripe.createToken`, but now that has changed to `Stripe.createPaymentMethod` and the token that I pass to the backend caused an error `You cannot supply a PaymentMethod ID as the 'source' parameter`...  my token now looks like "pm_..." and it's the only representation of the Card payment that I have at the time the customer is to be created. Can I use this somehow?

Comment: You'd want to set that `pm_` object as either `Subscription.default_payment_method` or `Customer.invoice_settings.default_payment_method`

Comment: OK and is it necessary for me to also set the newly created customers `default_source` at a later time in order for all of those customers payments to use that card, or is it sufficient to just set `invoice_settings.default_payment_method` on the customer?

Comment: Also wondering this. I've tried setting both `updatedInfo: { email: email , invoice_settings: { default_payment_method : paymentMethod.id }, default_source: paymentMethod.card.id, source: paymentMethod.card.id}})` but it seems only the `invoice_settings.default_payment_method` is actually being set. Will that suffice?

Comment: `default_source` is for the older `Sources` API, while `invoice_settings.default_payment_method` is for the newer `PaymentMethods` API. For the purposes of Subscriptions/Invoices, you just need to set the latter.